# a function of my bot only work when it run on my pc

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My goal is to create you a channel with your name when you react to one specific emoji on one specific message, .
i've actually tried that:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == **************:
        guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        user = bot.get_user(payload.user_id)
        print(is_user(payload.user_id))
        if is_user(payload.user_id):
            return
        chan = await guild.create_text_channel(user.name)
        await chan.set_permissions(user, read_messages=True,send_messages=True)
        new_user(payload.user_id,chan.id)
        await chan.send(f"hi there {user.mention}")
```

but this code only works on my PC: when I run it on my raspberry pi (or github with github action), this function doesn't work at all. I got a  traceback:

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "****.py", line 336, in on_raw_reaction_add
    chan = await guild.create_text_channel(user.name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

excepted result: a channel with the name of the person that reacted is created.

result: a traceback as shown

my pc is on windows 10, my raspberry pi runs on raspbian, and github action on ubuntu

Comment: Simply saying "doesn't work" it's too vague for SO... Are you getting any errors/tracebacks? What's the result, and what's the expected result? Take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks for you comment, i edited mine so its a little bit more precise.

Comment: Does the function even execute @Simon try debugging with print()

Comment: You provide too few information. What exactly are you doing on Github Action? Github Action is for running tests, not scripts 24/7. On your Raspberry it has to print something. If not you fail at the execution of your script.

Comment: I retried with print() and that time i got a traceback, I added it in the original question

@TinNguyen i used github actions because it made my bot run for 6h straight.I know its originally not for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your bot can't get the user out of the cache (this isn't only a problem of your bot) so the easiest way would be to fetch it from discord (but you shouldn't do this). Revised:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == **************:
        guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        user = await bot.fetch_user(payload.user_id)
        
        print(is_user(payload.user_id))
        
        if is_user(payload.user_id):
            return
        chan = await guild.create_text_channel(user.name)
        await chan.set_permissions(user, read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
        new_user(payload.user_id, chan.id)

        await chan.send(f"hi there {user.mention}")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Infortunately i got an error when running it:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'` and i dont have any idea of how to fix it. the error come from this line: `chan = await guild.create_text_channel(user.name)`

Comment: Then as I said you have to go with fetch_user(). Already updated the code so you can take a look

Comment: thank you but the name 'user' is still not defined so i got an error. I don't have any idea of what to define user. @FlexGames

Comment: That moment when you look too general on it and miss that you got member instead of user‍♂️ xD sorry, should now work as explained in the edited code

Comment: i don't understand why, but i still got an error (its start being boring) : `AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'name'` still have no idea of how to solve it .The problem appear when i use the second solution you gived

Comment: Yeah, seems like that's a coroutine.. so you have to put await in front sorry, yet I don't know what is a coroutine and what not
So, updated the code so it should (hopefully) work now

Comment: it now works perfectly thank you for your help.